# Why is Heroku raising this unusual error?

Tags: heroku, bots, discord.py

I made a Reaction Role Bot (Discord.py) a week ago, and when I'm hosting the Bot on my own PC everything is working perfectly fine. But when I#m pushing the File in Heroku and try to run it there, there are many Errors like this: https://gyazo.com/d40c7051aa7037a31101d51443314c90
I really don't know why there is an Error, because i changed absolutely nothing on the File.
Is there someone who maybe know why this happens and how i can get rid of this error?

Comment: Add a `requirements.txt` file with specific module versions, they can be obtained by running `pip freeze`, and also add a runtime.txt file with the version of python on your local machine like said [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) to minimise environment difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely Heroku pulled discord.py 1.5, and you are running an older version on your local machine.  v1.5 introduced support for gateway intents, see [this page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) on how to update your bot code to work with them.